# Why R base plot adds unwanted characters when I change number format?

Tags: r, plot, number-formatting

I am trying to make a log plot in R. By default, R plots the axis in scientific notation, but I need to plot them with decimal notation with one significant digit only.

The following code generates the plot:

```
plot(x = t, y = p1, type = "l", log = "y", xlim = xplotLim, ylim = yplotLim,
     xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Growth",
     lwd = 3)
)
```

The ylab is automatically created in scientific notation. I then tried to change the axis number format by removing the default axis and creating a new one:

```
plot(x = t, y = p1, type = "l", log = "y", xlim = xplotLim, ylim = yplotLim,
     xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Growth",
     main = "Growth vs time",
     lwd = 3,
     yaxt = "n",
     axis(2, at = axTicks(2), labels = sprintf("%.0f", axTicks(2)))
)
```

The axis is now exactlay as I want. However, it generates automatically a title (main) with the labels I generated with *sprintf* function.

As a third step, I tried to change the title by adding a main parameter:

```
plot(x = t, y = p1, type = "l", log = "y", xlim = xplotLim, ylim = yplotLim,
     xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Growth",
     main = "Growth vs time",
     lwd = 3,
     yaxt = "n",
     axis(2, at = axTicks(2), labels = sprintf("%.0f", axTicks(2))),
     main = "Growth vs Time"
)
```

Now the labels are printed below the xlab, and I have no idea how to remove them.

Follow a picture with all 3 plots:

[image]

Comment: `axis` is its own function, it doesn't go inside `plot`. Since it returns (*"numeric locations on the axis scale at which tick marks were drawn"*), its values are placed (unnamed) in various positional arguments in `plot`. Assuming `t` is numeric (unknown), it could be impacting any of the positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks!! That solves it :)